# Best decision tree type, when data has strong initial empirical assumptions, but future "nearby" outliers may be possible?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

Best decision tree type, when data has strong initial empirical assumptions, but future "nearby" outliers may be possible?

I've been confused about this relative to the algorithms available, like Random Forest, Boosted Trees, ... They prefer to estimate goodness and produce goodness of fit through some "mathematical measures". But in this case I have strong empirical measures, but which may contain deviation, when/if new observations contradict them. This suggests that methods that perform "automatic sensing of goodness of fit" might well perform worse than applying good intuitionistic empirical rules for splitting, corrected by possible future outliers. Because do the "automatic measures" understand the empirical phenomenon? It's also possible that the automatic method would reject the new observations as outliers, even if they would provide meaningful evidence.

So what model could be for this kind of scenario?

Example:

I know that by dividing feature A with a split at 40% (< 40% -> -1 and >= 40% -> 1) of range it models well the empirical observations. However it's possible that in the future there will come observations: (32%,1), (36%,1), (41%,-1), (43%,-1), ... that contradict the labels assigned originally, although they're still somewhat near to the 40% -rule. But based on the distribution of these new observations or their mean deviation, this could suggest readjusting the original 40% rule. E.g. since there's deviation of (8+4)/2=6 units to left and (1+3)/2=2 units to right, then this could suggest e.g. move 40% $\rightarrow$ 37% (since ratio of left:right is 3:1).

If we'd apply some automatic method to this, then it's possible that it would not set the original rule at 40%. It's also possible that by not doing this, it would retrain differently on future observations, since the reference point was different. OTOH, if we'd set the 40% manually, then how what model retrains relative to it?

Answer (score 1):

I read this as "How do we update a productionized model based on more production data"? If so, if data retention and volume is not a problem, retraining from scratch with all the data combined is a serious option. The main quesiton then is whether older data eventually becomes irrelevant (as is often observed in production models, but could depend a lot on the specific field) and should be discarded (or at least downweighted).

Another potential concern occurs, if the new data is influenced by model predictions of the old model. E.g. think of ranking internet search results based on what users click on, where whether users click on a link is not just determined by how relevant it is, but also by how high up you displayed it, which would be influenced by an model you are already using. That's an area of ongoing research, but may not be a concern in your particular problem.

Of course, there is no reason, why you could not re-start training a decision/regression tree ensemble by adding more trees (and popular packages have that option), which could be a sensible option, if e.g. the original data is no longer available or similar issues. One then has to determine though how to weight the original versus the new data, which one cannot explicitly do when only training some more on new data. One can also build a second model that takes the first model as an input, but this feels somewhat inelegant.

Perhaps if the new data has just way more volume (and at leas the same quality as the original data), it may be worth considering just using the new data to train a totally new model. It's more complicated when e.g. for the new data one is less sure of the correct labels (e.g. old data = small amount of high-quality labelled data, new data = hug volume of less reliably labelled data). Then, one could consider options like using label smoothing on the new data, but not (or to a lesser degree) on the older data (or in some other way reflecting that the labels of the older data might be more reliable than for the newer data).

Comment: "How do we update a productionized model based on more production data". Yes basically. A central issue has been, whether to focus on "best model" with limited data or reason that to figure out best model, smaller models must be initially grown, in order to learn about larger models. Thus perhaps, the initial models would later on become replaced with some others, but given current data, it's not necessarily (or it could be) possible to decide on "generally best model". These have different costs during production.

Comment: And it's not trivial as to how to weight "strong initial assumptions on small training data" to "strong statistical assumptions on future of large training data".

Comment: It's not even trivial as to whether one needs a larger training data in order to make correct assumptions. But studying all these possibilities would be taxing.